# Two routers connected to one DSL modem

Tags: networking, router, modem, adsl, dsl

Let's say that currently I have a VDSL modem connected to the phone wall-socket: it takes the VDSL line/signal.

Then I've a router, connected from the WAN port, through ethernet, to the modem. The router takes the public IP assigned from the DHCP server of my ISP, and it shares the connection between all the computers connected to the embedded switch of the router itself (i.e. in the LAN with private IPs).

This is a simply, basic configuration for a *DSL home connection.

Now my question is: would it be possible to add another router and have assigned a second public IP from my ISP? The new configuration should be the following:

- modem connected to the phone wall-socket for the DSL line/signal, and to a switch/hub through ethernet
- both router (the original and the new added one, with two different private IPs) connected to the switch/hub to which the modem is connected
- some computers connected to the original router (by keeping the gateway address unchanged), other computers connected to the new router (by modifying the gateway address with the private IP of the new router)

Computers connected through old and new router, should navigate on internet with two different public IPs.

Could such a thing be feasible? Or the WAN port of a router must always be connected DIRECTLY to the modem (i.e. without passing through a switch/hub). Or maybe it would my ISP does not permit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have 2 connections on 1 VDSL cable.

If you want an extra connection, the ISP will have to install an additional cable.

Comment: ok, but the DSL modem which takes the DSL signal it remains only one, so only one DSL line, one 'DSL cable', but it would simply 'shares' this line to two routers.

Comment: You can route the connection you get in a thousand ways, but you cannot have 2 public IPs over one single VDSL connection. What is the model of the modem/router from the ISP?

Comment: Actually an AVM FritzBox, which includes DSL modem and router in only one single device (so the situation I described in the question isn't really what I have, but it was only to make the question more clear).

Comment: I like FritzBox. They are good devices, the default interface is full-featured. You can set up VLANS to divide up your private network, but you will still have one public IP